# Return data from Service, not promise

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking to have a bit of a cleaner controller to not muddy it up with promise api stuff.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

**Some Service**

```
...
.service('SomeService', function SomeService($http) {
  this.getAllItems = function() {
    return $http.get('api/items')
      .success(function(data) {
        return data;
      });
```

**Controller**

```
...
SomeService.getAllItems().then(function(response) {
  $scope.items = response.data;
});
...
```

I'm trying to avoid the extra function call on the promise and assign items directly like so:

```
$scope.items = SomeService.getAllItems();
```

Is this possible?  I've tried calling the then within the service, and it still ends up returning a promise object once it's resolved in the controller, but I'm probably doing something wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: That would make the call non-async - what's wrong with using `.then()`?

Comment: Nothing is "wrong" with it, just feels ... dirty, I don't know.

Comment: I'm assuming by this comment, the `.then()` callback delegates once the response is received, otherwise it'd block?

Comment: If you are using ngRoute you can use the resolve property of the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$resource` class to do it. This is [from the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick
>   since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then
>   rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering,
>   once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated
>   with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the
>   new data. This means that in most cases one never has to write a
>   callback function for the action methods.

Comment: Hrm, this might be exactly what I'm looking for!